# rootProject.ext.varName vs rootProject.varName

Tags: gradle

say gradle rootProject build.gradle has below define:

```
ext {
    varName = "varValue"    
}
```

Then in Module build.gradle, use it as below:

```
def xxx = rootProject.ext.varName
```

But looks like without the ext, it works as well:

```
def xxx = rootProject.varName
```

What's the difference between this two styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can infer, there is a difference between accessing properties directly from your project as compared to using the [ExtraPropertiesExtension](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html) (.ext).

When you do this:

```
rootProject.varName
```

The logic goes through your entire project to search for this property and may result in an exception (MissingPropertyException) in the case it doesn't exist.

When you do this:

```
rootProject.ext.varName
```

the logic searches directly in the ExtraProperty scope.

Comment: (MissingPropertyException) can also be raised for rootProject.ext.varName if it doesn't exist, right.